# Fabric - Is there any way to capture run stdout?

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to do the following:

```
output = run("ls -l backups")
for line in output.split("/n"):
    do_stuff(line)
```

Any way of having the `stdout` of `ls` sent to `output`?

---

To be more specific: I'm using a CLI app called `s3cmd` which does something similar to `ls`, but with remote Amazon S3 buckets.

So, a replacement for `ls` won't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 28):

Exactly what you are asking for should be happening. From the [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run):

> run will return the result of the remote program’s stdout as a single (likely multiline) string.

`run()`, and related commands like `local()` and `sudo()`, return an `_AttributeString` object that is just a wrapper around stdout with attribute access to additional information like failure/success booleans, stderr, the command run, etc. The result object also has a `stdout` attribute, which is just more explicit.

To troubleshoot, `print type(output), output` to be sure the response is what you expect. Examine `output.failed` and `output.stderr`. It could be the command isn't doing what you expect, there is no "backups" directory, etc.

Comment: `...
output = run(cmd)
print 'command output: {}'.format(output.stdout)
...`

Comment: you may have to strip some unicode characters: for instance, use `... .stdout.strip('\x00')` before conversion to int

Answer (score 17):

Try as below using String IO

```
from fabric.api import *
from StringIO import StringIO

fh = StringIO()
run("ls -l backups", stdout=fh)

fh.seek(0)
for line in fh.readlines():
    do_stuff(line)
```

Comment: You might forget to `fh.seek(0)`.

Comment: when i do this i am getting a blank content into "line"

Comment: This referes to an older version of fabric: `TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stdout'`

Answer (score 15):

In case you need to use run(), you can do it like this:

```
with settings(
    hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),
    warn_only=True
):
    command = 'ls -l backups'
    output = run(command)
    for line in output.splitlines():
        do_stuff(line)
```

For local() there is a bit more simple solution:

```
command = 'ls -l backups'
output = local(command, capture=True)
for line in output.splitlines():
    do_stuff(line)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. the top solution contains all the fabric formatting (IP, fabric command, ...)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this if you are using the `local()` api, by setting the `capture=True`

```
@task
def login_ecr_docker():
    ecr_login = local("aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2", capture=True)
    docker_login = ecr_login.stdout
    status = local(docker_login, capture=True)
    print (status.stdout)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try split using "`\r\n`":

```
output = run("ls -l backups")
output_stdout = output.stdout.split("\r\n")
```

Comment: The solution I was looking for! Is there a good way to remove all the escape codes to save it into a variable (so not just using print) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply return it:

```
def output():
    return run("ls -l backups")
a = execute(output, host=hostname)
print a
```

a will be dictionary of results.

Comment: that's good answer in general but I think OP is looking for way to retrieve one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The [current fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/#what-is-fabric) uses `hide=True`, e.g.

> ```
> result = Connection('web1.example.com').run('uname -s', hide=True)
> ```

It can then be accessed with `result.stdout`. For your case, it should be

```
output = run("ls -l backups", hide=True)
for line in output.stdout.split("/n"):
    do_stuff(line)
```