# Python execute ssh command(SSH server just for remote port forwarding) and capture the output

Tags: python, ssh

Currently, I am using this command to run the ssh server for remote port forwarding using Serveo

```
subprocess.call('ssh -R 80:127.0.0.1:5000 serveo.net', shell=True)
```

I need to extract the URL from the ssh command and assign it into a variable. Is there any way to get the output?

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Have a look at this question about [capturing ssh output with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21443690/5476782)

Comment: @PaoloMossini **Forwarding HTTP traffic from https://subdomain.serveo.net** it will keep on running and will not stop, like python Flask

Answer (score -1):

With the `bash` module:

```
import bash
b = bash('ls tests.py')
b.stdout 'tests.py\n'
b.stderr ''
```